# Bad [language]!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across the bad [language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language) tag on a question in the Close Votes queue and it appears to be a ripe candidate for burnination.

This tag has 115 questions, the first of which dates from March of this year. It has no description.

Looking at the [criteria](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071/7508700) for burnination:

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

There is no usage guidance in the tag wiki for it. The 115 questions in the tag seem to be roughly split three ways between:

- Posts about foreign languages and linguistics (e.g. dictionary databases, messages in different languages, translations)
- Posts about programming languages and syntax, or code conversions
- Posts about language settings in various contexts

And a smattering of questions that don't seem to have any reason for a tag called [language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language).

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

As there's no guiding concept behind the tag, it can't really be on-topic. Only [one question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62053055/what-is-a-base-35-numerical-system-called) has [language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language) as its only tag, but that appears to be off-topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Searching for [language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language) seems unlikely to be helpful for anyone because of the varied assortment of questions using the tag. It does have 325 watchers, however, but I would suggest that they must have a wide range of reasons for watching an unclear tag.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

Clearly not from the above.

Comment: as always t5he tag doesn't hurt, should be better described what falls under it and kept alive

Comment: @nbk no. There are better tags to describe the subjects. Like `locale` or `programming-language`. Where the question didn’t use the tag in a way already covered by existing non-ambiguous tags, the question was invariably off topic. The tag *did* hurt because it made it harder to define the question subject clearly.

Comment: languag for language settings and askin about multilanguage options , is alright and should be kept alive

Comment: @nbk you seem to confuse wether something is on topic with the tag being useful. For asking about multi language options, use *locale* or *internationalisation*. Those terms are much clearer and unambiguous. You *can* ask about those subjects but there are better tags for them.

Comment: We still have [tag:multilingual] and other tags that are more than sufficient. There was no telling what this tag meant. Programming language or natural language? It readily violates [burninate criteria #1 and #4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/244695)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Mumbl.. mumbl.. *<inaudible>* language *cough* ambiguous mumbl.

Mumbl..  closed some *mumbl*. *<inaudible>* deleted others *mumbl* retagged *mumbl*.

Tag’s gone.

Comment: Fastest burninate ever

Comment: @Machavity it was just 115 posts; it was, at most a *slight-raise-in-temperaturation*.

Comment: That is [0.000585%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions) (5.85 ppm) of the questions.

Comment: Can't believe stuff like this still get a higher score than most other answers :,).